# In Extended Events what is the difference between rpc_completed and sql_batch_completed?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, extended-events

I understand that `rpc_completed` is defined as the completion of a remote procedure call and `sql_batch_completed` is the completion of a t-sql batch.  However can anyone explain in concrete terms what the difference is?  When should I use one and when should I use the other?  Will most/all SQL commands trigger both events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is how the command is executed by the client. The client can directly execute a stored procedure or the client can send a sql batch.

To call a stored procedure from .NET you would use

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

and to execute a batch you would use

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

There are other things you need to set up like the connection, but the above shows the difference between the two execution modes.

Comment: So if I want catch every time a system SP is called I'll want to capture both rpc_completed and sql_batch_completed?  Are there any other events I should capture?

Comment: if you just want to capture the fact that it was executed, i would use the `sp_completed` (or sqlserver.module_end for XE) event. If you are interested in the parameters too, have a look at http://sqlity.net/en/976/capturing-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-call/

Comment: Also, read about how to capture parameter values here: https://www.scarydba.com/2018/09/24/extended-events-and-stored-procedure-parameter-values/